# Directory for compiled GL-shader

Tags: 12.04, drivers, 16.04, steam

I have small problem GL-shaders.
I switched from ubuntu 12.04 to 16.04 and from proprietary to open source driver. After fast closing CS:GO is have performance problems: while shooting FPS falls to 10-12 pro second. In ubuntu 12.04 and I have simply deleted from

```
~/.AMD/cache
```

all compiled shaders.
And performance come back to normal.

But on open source driver I couldn't find directory with pre-compiled shaders.

So where are they?

- OS Ubuntu 16.04
- GS:GO latest
- steam latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood how to solve this problem.
Somehow GS:GO determined wrong CPU core quantity(multi thread rendering is enabled in graphics settings).
After I set in CS:GO launch options that my CPU has 4 cores it began to work without any problems and lags.